Does workflow core support hierarchical workflows in ASP .NET Core?
We're developing an ASP.NET Core 8 application that utilizes the Workflow Core library for managing long-running processes. Our current workflow design requires nested execution, where a specific step within a parent workflow needs to pause and wait for a child workflow to complete successfully before proceeding.
Our goals:

We aim to break down our complex workflow into smaller, reusable sub-workflows for improved maintainability and code organization.
We require the parent workflow to wait for the sub-workflow's completion before transitioning to the subsequent step.

While Workflow Core offers Decision Branching for creating conditional branches with multiple steps, it doesn't directly address our scenario. Decision branching relies on conditions to determine which path to execute, and in our case, we simply need to ensure the sub-workflow finishes before continuing in the parent workflow. Our initial attempts using the Workflow Core library haven't achieved the desired wait functionality for nested workflow execution.
Ideally, we'd like to understand:

Can Workflow Core achieve the desired nested execution with a parent workflow waiting for a sub-workflow to complete?
If feasible, what's the appropriate approach to implement nested workflows within the capabilities of the Workflow Core library?


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
